# How to switch AC using FETs

Tags: microcontroller, mosfet, ac

I am trying to control a lamp powered by AC current from my wall outlet. To control the lamp I am trying to use a 5 V microcontroller, Arduino to be exact.

My two questions are:

1. Is there a way to use a FET to achieve this? If so, how?
2. What type of FET would be the best to do this?

Comment: The question is as follows: How do I switch AC with a TRIAC?

Comment: Use a relay, that way you get some isolation.

Comment: Get a pre-built mains-switching module that provides safe isolation from mains voltages. That way you won't electrocute yourself or burn your house down.

Answer (score 12):

Use the FET to drive the coil of a relay.

Or skip the FET and get an SSR.

Connecting an Arduino output to a FET connected to mains AC does not provide safety isolation, so leads to a risk of electrocution if there is a fault and you touch anything connected to the Arduino.

Comment: triac output ssrs/optos etc used to be good for switching incandescent lights, but probably need to get fet based ssr for modern LED bulb.

Answer (score 8):

> Is there any way to use a FET to achieve this? If so, how?

Yes, many AC+DC SSR (solid state relays) use FETs.

[image: Solid state relays with MOSFETs]

Driving this requires some effort. There is a Texas Instruments application note, [TIDUC87A](http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/tiduc87a/tiduc87a.pdf), describing it.

You might also want to consider using [TRIACs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TRIAC). Driving those is slightly easier. A relay is even more simplistic.

> What type of FET would be the best to do this?

N-Channels are most used since these are cheaper and more available. Obviously you need to be able to withstand the peak voltage. Which for 240 VAC this is 340 volt. You'd **at least** need 600 V MOSFETs, preferably higher due to mains transients.