# Thermal protection of triac in floor heating controller

Tags: heat, protection, triac, thermal

Hello there fellow engineers.

I'm in the middle of design controller for floor heating. The idea is to have a triac based design with zero detection circuit, for each control point (each heating cable will have it's own controller) and a bunch of those controllers will go into a DIN35 case. Device dimensions will be something around 14x85mm, this forbids me from using a big heat sink. Cables that I use varies from 500 to 1500W (230VAC) depending on the room.
(this design should be modular, I don't want to make a single ~8channel controller. By modular I mean that each triac has its own zero detection and a separate board and then N of those boards are connected to some kind of uC and the uC has the entire logic, also I want to use this for lights so there will be many devices connected to different RCD in a single DIN case)

For now I have a relay based controller and I can tell that in normal operation (floor temperature is stable) I use only <20% of the overall cables power, so at those power levels triac will emit <2W of heat, which is almost ok for to220 case :)
The problem starts when I want to change the floor temperature (or heat up from low temp, e.g. when returning from vacations) because some rooms will take like 1h of full power to heat-up, and for a 1500W system this is ~7W of heat on a TO220 case... which is unacceptable.

To somehow handle this problem I started to design a thermal protection circuit on the high voltage side, based on NTC resistor, the idea is that when the temperature exceed some threshold U4 will start to conduct and will pull the "zero detection" signal to ground which then can be detected by uC as Overheat and then, uC will disable Q1 for some time.
But there are a bunch of problems with this.

#1 The design gets complicated for such a simple device, and the power supply needs to be replicated on each device, not nice :/  specially that I need to put devices on back and even then they barely fit due to size of C5
#2 U3 has a big temperature drift... to compensate this, I would need another stabilizer, which makes #1 even worst
#3 Despite #1 and #2 there is no calibration point in this schema, so the temperature will vary between devices :/
All of those points led me away from this kind of protection.

SO the question is, can you guys recommend me some other way of thermal protection for this design?
Can I put the NTC on 'low' side and bend it over to high?
Or maybe suggest a way to fit a big heat sink on such small PCB?
For big systems, connect multiple modules in parallel?
or maybe crank up the voltage? :] (I have 3phase supply)
Or don't do thermal protection at all?

[image: Schematics]

this view is a PCB without thermal protection, just for reference

[image: PCB without thermal protection]

Comment: I don't get the concept of having ZCD for each triac, instead of one on the  MCU board. Further, a comercial 6A SSR  is small without issues you describe.

Comment: I use all 3 phases for heating, so 3 different modules in single DIN case can be powered from 3 different phases, so each ZCD must be coupled with a triac. Also from the pulse output I can tell if everything with the power supply is ok (if no pulses, no power, something hapend, please check ;) )
Also, SSR are not cheap (they are order of magnitude more expensive then triac at least the ones that I checked in my supplier) and they also have problems with voltage drop and with "high" internal resistance, so I think that the thermal problem will not be entirely fixed

Comment: aren't there opto triacs with the zx circuit built in? MOSFETs might have less power loss.
Commercial designs would use a thermal fuse, or bimetallic switch for thermal protection. Your solution probably wouldn't pass as a safety circuit.

Comment: I once put ten 100k 10W resistors (thermal greased) into an 8" square metal enclosure, used as 500VDC loads (2.5W each.)  Thought for sure that having them all "on" would overheat the box, but it did not.  Box would rise maybe 20°C at most.  Point is, if you can sink that heat to an enclosure, problem might be mitigated.

Comment: @Kartman this grade mosfets are really expensive, and I need two of them for a single module, so this will bump the costs considerably. Also I need zero crossing info to make the timings right (I want to be able to control lights also with this design)

Comment: You made no mention of cost constraints in your question. Besides, your design has a lot of superfluous parts adding to the cost. It sounds like you’ll need a heatsink, so thats a mechanical problem. You’ll also need thermal protection - whether that is for a number of boards on a common heatsink or for each board. Also, don’t expect to do phase control without an inductor and snubber.

Comment: @Kartman yes, I didn't mention any constraints, and I should, noted :) will try to be more specific when asking my next question. What do you mean by superfluous parts, what parts do you have on mind? I plan to use phase control for lights only, that's why I didn't add an inductor I thought it will not be needed.
Ok I'll rethink my design and try to fit everything in this small case.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things you can try, and only your application will determine which works best for you.

1. If you know the temperature differential (been off for a long time case), you could do a duty cycle.  For heaters the period is usually on the order of 10s of seconds.
2. Component heat (power dissipation) is a function of voltage drop. So reduce the voltage drop in your circuit by using a mechanical relay.
3. Related to #1, establish your max duty cycle that the circuit can do without overheating, and never go above that.
4. Use a higher power triac, ie. in a larger package, that can dissipate more heat.  Though I think this will only get you a little margin because you still have the same power being dissipated in a small space.
5. Bergquist makes a thick squishy thermal pad that you may be able to use to get the heat to a different surface easier than a conventional heatsink.

EDIT:

6. If you have the room you can use [back to back mosfets](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/369214/166672).  Rdson in the 10mΩ dissipates very little power compared to a triac. Fancy electronics cost more though.

Comment: 1. I thought about this and I really don't know if this is safe or not. But worth trying 
2. I am using those right now, but I fear that they will wear to quickly. (some of them have ~60k of on-off cycles and I didn't use them even a year, I can increase hysteresis but it is 
2°C right now, I don't want to increase this value)

3. This is a good idea... I'll try it

4. you saw the PCB, it's tiny... I'll try to put this triac along the longer side of PCB and then fit a bigger heat sink

5. Thanks for suggestion.